# Each domain as a separate virtualhost - prevent access outside the domain

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server, domain, virtual-host

I have Debian server with Apache, php, mysql, proftpd. Then I have 6 domains on it. Each domain is one folder (with joomla, drupal, etc). Now I need to completely separate all each directory from another domain directory - I mean what should I do to prevent any access within one domain (directory) to another domain?

So any script should not be able to access other files in system outside of domain (something much more safer than open basedir). When someone attacks domain with joomla he should not be able to change/access other files in another domain or in server.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can go into various layers for this.

First thing would be to move the files all in different directories
Then use open_basedir in php to lock the include directories per vhost.
To make it more secure you can either run a php-fpm pool per vhost, or use something like suPHP to run the php process per user, allowing you to lock down the directories to only allow these specific users to access the files.

I hope this makes sense

Comment: yes, I have files all in different directories. And now I need "bulletproof" solution (not more / less secure) but thanks for your more solutions. Which one would you recommend to make it bulletproof? (ideally script independent - or if I install support for other scripts than php in the future)

Comment: - php-fpm pool per vhost, 
- open_basedir to lock down include path